# Rails Select one random listings for premium users

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, random

In my rails app, I have Users and Listings. The Listings belong to a User. Listing has user_id and its filled with users id who is creating the listing.

A user can be a premium user, gold user or silver user.

What I want is for each premium user, select one random listing to show in premium listings.

I can do it in O(n**2) time or n+1 query as follow:

```
users_id = User.where(:role => "premium").pluck[:id]
final_array = Array.new
users_id.each do |id|
  final_array << Listing.where(:user_id => id).sample(1)
end
final_array
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
listings = Listing.select(
  <<~SQL
    DISTINCT ON (users.id) users.id, 
    listings.*, 
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY users.id ORDER BY random())
  SQL
)
  .joins(:user)
  .includes(:user)
  .where(users: { role: :premium })
```

It gives a random Listing for **every** premium user.

It produces the only request to db and also it won't make an extra request for getting listing's user, so you are free to do something like this:

```
listings.each do |listing|
  p listing.user
end
```

Comment: I don't think you need both `joins(:user)` and `includes(:user)`.

Comment: without `includes(:user)` there will be a separated request to db to get listing's user. `includes(:user)` can be replaced with `eager_load(:user)` if you are confused by having `joins` and `includes` in one statement

Answer (score 0):

```
random_user_listings = []

User.includes(:listings).where(role: "premium").find_each do |user|
  random_user_listings << user.listings.sample(1)
end

random_user_listings
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid N+1 query you need to combine them, perform query one time like this:

```
list = Listing.includes(:user).where(:role => "premium").sample(1)
```

Feel free to deal with list instead of Listing. Because now you're dealing with variable, not Query.

```
ids = list.pluck(:user_id).uniq
```

Getting array of ids like above and doing further steps as you did (but with list, not Listing)
Need to be noticed that, when you deal with Model you're dealing with QUERY. Avoiding doing that in loop statement.

Comment: It'll give just a random Listing for a random premium user. As I understood the author wants to get a random Listing for every premium user. Am I right? 

Comment: yes, exact for every premium user. I tell him the way to avoid N+1. When list has values, he will deal with variable, not query any more.

Comment: I just added more in answer.